Give local Windows account access to NAS
I have a NAS at an office. No domain (yes, I realize I should). The NAS has some awful OS and has its own user management. I run a script when users logon to map the NAS as a drive.
I'm trying to install backup software on a user's Windows 10 computer to backup the NAS. The documentation for the backup software says to go to Services and change the logon from Local System Account to a user with Read permissions.



But the NAS does not let me add a local Windows account because it is only searching for users on the NAS OS:



And I can't add a NAS user to the Services Logon for the same reason.
Any suggestions on how to get these permissions to work?

since you don't have domain you are using SMB in a workgroup model. that means you have to create the users on each system using the same password, and maintain them on a system by system basis. so you add a user on the NAS, assign that user the permissions, and when the person accesses the nas from windows using their user account, they will use their credentials to login to the NAS as the NAS user.

@FrankThomas Yes, but that doesn't explain how to get the Services Logon to add the NAS users.

Reread what the man above said. you need do add an account on both systems. Then use that account in the first screenshot...

so lets say you have userA on windows, using password1. you need to create userA with password1 on the NAS. when you assign permissions on the NAS you use the NAS's copy of the user. when  you schedule tasks or configure services on the Windows PC, you use the Windows instance of the user. In a workgroup model, each system only knows its own local accounts
